# wordpress website doesnt load properly on intranet

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have designed a wordpress website in xampp and it looks all good in localhost.

But when I access the website from other pc via intranet/lan it looks all messed up and developer tools in chrome says following:

> "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

How is this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What URL you are using to access website on Intranet/LAN?

You may need to update URL's (e.g. siteurl) in your database to make it accessible on network.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an alternative answer but have you tried using [Local by Flywheel](https://local.getflywheel.com/)? It allows you to create a local environment for Wordpress but also allows you to give out a "Live Link"... which essentially allows anyone to view the site on your local environment.